# Update Author Name in all Commits in git after particular date

Tags: git, bash, commit, git-bash, git-commit

I tried it but could not find how can I compare GIT_COMMITTER_DATE with some specific Date to update author and committer email.. This is what I have tried but I need to add date comparison in if conditions extra to update particular commits otherwise it's picking up very old commits too..

Here AFTER_DATE is date after which I want to update author email..

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
NAME="Kautsya Kanu"
WRONG_EMAIL="kauts_kanu@Kautsyas-MacBook-Pro.local"
CORRECT_EMAIL="example@gmail.com"
AFTER_DATE="2017-03-31"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" -a "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "$NAME" ]
then
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" -a "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "$NAME" ]
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Answer (score 1):

If TL;DR: see the bottom section, where I suggest what you probably really want to do instead.

## How to test dates in `git filter-branch`

There are multiple parts to this problem and you must decide which ones you care about.

- All Git commits have *two* time stamps: author, and committer.
- Time stamps have two parts: a Unix style "seconds since 1 Jan 1970", and a time zone.
- `git filter-branch` copies commits; selectors (passed to `git rev-list`) select *which* commits get copied.  To make the copy, Git effectively<sup>1</sup> extracts the original commit, runs all your filters to make any changes you desire, and then makes a new commit from the result.  If the new commit is bit-for-bit identical to the original, it *is* the original, i.e., the "copy" takes no extra space.
- After doing the copying, any "positive" references (branch and tag names) are mapped to the copies.

That last re-mapping step is why, after `git filter-branch` completes, `git log` shows you the new (modified) copies instead of the original (unmodified) commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>A great deal of `git filter-branch` is simply code to avoid doing this the slow and stupid "extract, modify, rebuild" way, *because* this is incredibly slow.  Being smart about it can speed things up so that instead of taking, say, 24 hours, a filter-branch command might complete in just ten minutes.  But to understand what you are doing, you can use this simpler mental model: you are essentially re-copying the entire repository to a new repository in which the new commits probably have different hash ID numbers.

---

#### The hard part: time stamps

In many places, Git lets you write simple expressions like `2017-03-31`.  Filter-branch is not one of these places.  Moreover, each filter is a little bit of shell script.  There are basic tests built in to the shell: `test $num1 -ge $num2`, for instance, will test whether the expanded numeric value of `$num1` is greater than or equal to the expand value of `$num2`.

When you are filtering a commit, Git has put the author and committer dates into environment variables `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`.  What is in these, though, is precisely what is in the commit itself.  Let's take a look at an example commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 52cbd85298ed8ee95776f93ddb0eede02a36c539
parent 71e38d40e93aa1357dad53f1599c2a1c00b54dc5
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1491895625 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1491895625 -0700

Eleventh batch for 2.13

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

So `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` would, in this case, contain `1491895625 -0700`, and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE is identical.  For comparison, here is a snippet from a commit where they are different:

```
author Hiroshi Shirosaki <h.shirosaki gmail.com> 1488779947 +0900
committer Eric Wong <e 80x24.org> 1488922143 +0000
```

If you decide to use time stamps, you must figure out how to compare the time stamp(s) you care about, with the equivalent of "2017-03-31".  If we ignore the time *zone* information, we can just pick a number like `1491000000` and convert that to local time:

```
$ date -r 1491000000
Fri Mar 31 15:40:00 PDT 2017
```

so if using 3:40 PM Pacific Daylight time works for you, that number would work.  We can then compare `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and/or `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to 1491000000, although we still have to snip off the pesky time zone offset:

```
date_exceeds_1491000000() {
    test $1 -ge 1491000000
}
```

and now we can write:

```
if date_exceeds_1491000000 $GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
```

and let the shell's argument-splitting take care of things (`$1` will be the part before the white space, with `$2` holding the zone).

It is up to you to figure out how to combine the example above with your environment filter; most critical here is whether you want to filter based on *author* date, *committer* date, or some combination of both.

#### An easier way, but with some caveats: not using the time stamps

You could, on the other hand, choose *not* to test the time stamps directly within the filter-branch code at all.  Instead, you can let the `git rev-list` specifiers choose the time stamps.  That lets you use `--since`, which *does* let you write convenient "2017-03-31" style dates:

```
git filter-branch ... --since=2017-03-31 ...
```

This is much simpler and has the advantage of not even bothering to copy commits that come before the time stamp.  However, it has flaws.  These may not be fatal, but you should consider them.

First, you no longer control which of `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` are used.  Git uses the committer timestamp.  If that's the one you want, great! :-)

Second, there is a problem if commits have dates in "skewed" order.  Consider the following bit of a branch:

```
...--E--F--G--H--...
```

where each uppercase letter represents a commit.  Suppose that `E`'s commit date is yesterday, `F`'s is two weeks ago, `G`'s is today, and `H`'s is one week ago.  In other words, commit `E`, which happened first of these four, happened yesterday; then, two weeks before that, commit `F` happened after commit `E`.

This seems impossible—and is not all that common.  But it *does* happen, especially if the commits are done on different computers and one of them has the wrong date.  If I commit something now, and then set the date back two weeks, and then commit something else, the later *commit* has the earlier *time stamp*.

In this case, `git rev-list` may<sup>2</sup> *skip* some commits, leaving "holes" in the selected commits.  When fed to `git filter-branch`, this will result in the copying also skipping those commits.  If the `--since` cutoff is a few days ago, we will copy `E` and `G`, but not `F` and `H`, so that the new chain reads:

```
...--E'--G'--...
```

where `E'` is the new copy of `E`, and `G'` is the new copy of `G`.

If your commit timestamps are all in the correct order, this never actually happens, and all is well: you may use `--since` to limit the commits to be copied.

---

<sup>2</sup>Git has some optimizations that try to stop running through commits, based on their time stamps.  I have seen these cut commits off in "interesting" ways that can affect this.  I think these optimizations are somewhat broken—Git probably should scan the entire repository and set a configuration flag, e.g., `core.trust-internal-timestamps`, to `true` if the commit time stamps are correct and to `false` if not, with the value initially unset meaning "need to scan and set based on result".  An initial clone can scan and set the value, and adding new commits (`git fetch` and `git commit` for instance) can check whether to adjust the set-value from `true` to `false` if incoming commits violate the time-stamp rules.

It's also not really clear how the time zone offsets are supposed to work.  Internally, Git just does a `strtoul` on the numeric value, ignoring the time zone.  See [function `parse_commit_date` in `commit.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf11a67975b057a144618badf16dc4e3d25b9407/commit.c#L93).

---

## Summary, plus simplest method of all

You can either test dates explicitly, by doing your own conversion from `2017-03-31` to number and using the `test` command (which is also the `[` command that you are already using to compare author name and email); or you can use `--since` to limit the set of commits that you copy.  Which to use, and whether `--since` suffices at all, is up to you.

There's one last way to do this that is much simpler, but is not what you asked for.  You should still consider it.  Just run `git log --topo-order` (or use `--all --decorate --oneline --graph`, which you can and should remember as A DOG: **a**ll, **d**ecorate, **o**neline, **g**raph; note that `--graph` implies `--topo-order`) and scan through the result until you see some good places to *stop* filtering.  Note down these commit hashes, then add them as negated references to your revision selectors:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter ...your-filter-here... \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags \
    ^123456789abcdef ^feedbeefdeadc0ffee
```

(here `123456789abcdef` is short for one of those commit hashes).  The negated commit hashes *stop* `git filter-branch` from looking at that commit and any earlier commits reachable from that commit, so it will not copy them.  Since you are not using a `--parent-filter`, any commit that comes *after* that point, that you do copy, will refer back to the original uncopied commit.  This avoidance-of-copy is *graph*-based, so there is no potential for "skipped" commits the way there is for `--since`, if the dates are a bit broken.

In other words, the commits you *don't* copy stick around and are unchanged.  They take no time to filter, which makes `git filter-branch` go faster—maybe *much* faster, converting a four hour filtering job into a ten second job, for instance (this depends on how many commits you *do* copy vs how many you *don't*).  And, it takes care of not touching commits "earlier" than some point, *regardless of their internal date stamps.*